# Weird output when using ssh inside a loop over a file

Tags: shell-script, ssh, files, tty, array

The script is to read a file that contains multiple lines, each line containing a tab-delimited array.  I want to execute some remote commands that take those array elements as arguments, with sudo permission.  Here is the example script:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line
do
  echo ${line[0]}
  ssh -tty -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${line[0]} 'sudo echo ${line[1]}; sudo echo ${line[2]}' 
done < nodes.txt
```

Here is the example input file:

```
rivervm-1       dc2     rack1
rivervm-2       dc2     rack2
rivervm-3       dc2     rack3
rivervm-4       dc2     rack4
```

The output should be 12 variables, each in a new line.  However, this is what I got:

```
rivervm-1
rivervm-2   dc2 rack2
rivervm-3   dc2 rack3
rivervm-4   dc2 rack4

Connection to rivervm-1 closed.
```

Any idea?

Comment: The shell won't expand variables within single quotes.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks!  I've updated the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `ssh` command is eating your input (coming from `nodes.txt`), append `< /dev/null` to it. Appending a `&` has the same effect since, by putting `ssh` into background, it detaches it from standard input.

Secondly, as noticed by Kusalananda, your variable `${line[1]}` and `${line[2]}` are not substituted because they are inside single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comment of @Kusalananda, shell won't expand variables within single quotes.  That explains why `echo` inside `ssh` does not work.  After I replace single quotes with double quotes, the output is like:

```
rivervm-1
rivervm-2   dc2 rack2
rivervm-3   dc2 rack3
rivervm-4   dc2 rack4
dc2
rack1
Connection to rivervm-1 closed.
```

Still, it only executes the commands on rivervm-1, but not the rest.

I've found a solution to this:  adding '&' to the end of ssh command.  Could anyone explain to me why this works?  Thanks!

Comment: I have just added an explanation to my answer.